# Drawing a discontinuous line

Tags: matlab, plot, line, visualization, matlab-figure

How can I get this graph in MATLAB? This is the payoff of down-and-out call option with barrier `B=120`, strike `K=100`. Should I somehow combine two graphs in one picture?

[image]

Comment: What, specifically, is your problem here? How to find equations for these lines? How to evaluate them? How to create a plot in MATLAB? How to make your plot blue? How to add labels to your axis?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do it in various ways. Here are two of them:

#### Option 1:

```matlab
function q54615569(B, K)
y = @(x)(x>=B).*(x-K);
x = 0:2*K;
figure(); plot(x, y(x));
xlabel('S(T)');
```

[image]

#### Option 2:

```matlab
function q54615569(B, K)
y = @(x)x-K;
x = 0:2*K;
figure(); hL = plot( x(x<=B), 0.*x(x<=B), x(x>=B), y(x(x>=B)) );
set(hL, 'Color', lines(1), 'Linestyle', 'none', 'Marker','o','MarkerSize', 2,...
  'MarkerFaceColor', lines(1));
xlabel('S(T)');
```

[image]

Comment: There’s another option: add a NaN value where the gap needs to be.

Comment: @CrisLuengo That's true. The reason I didn't iunclude it is because I wanted to stick with anonymous functions, and having them output a `NaN` for a specific input needlessly complicates the expression and hurts the readability of the otherwise simple-ish solution.